# Reading from networkstream without losing data

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I have client-server application. I need way to asynchronously peek what client sends to server and react accordingly. I have access only to network stream therefore if i use NetworkStream.Read() i lose data that was in the stream. I tried to write data back to stream but then i still am not able to access stream on the server side.

Is there any way to peek the NetworkStream? If i'm not mistaken there is way to that by using socket object and invoking Receive method. Problem is that socket property in NetworkStream is protected so i can't use it. Can i access somehow this particular socket ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to peek the socket's data without removing it from the stream? There is a `Read(buff, 0, length, MSG_PEEK);` that would return the data without removing it from the stream.

Comment: Situation looks as follows: client send request to server, i need to peek the stream if request does contain specific message. Server should receive request after i peek the stream. Problem is that user sends request then processing begins. Server may be requested to stopprocessing in the mean time, that is why i need to listen on the same stream asynchronously. I have access only to stream, not underlying socket.

Comment: humm, I see. There is something call urgent data which is different that normal data. I'm afraid you need to access the socket in order to get to the urgent data though. When you see an urgent packet is an indication that you want the server to stop processing. Why can't you access the underlying socket?

Comment: Baceuse if i'm not mistaken NetworkStream does not expose underlying socket for me to access. Am I right?

Comment: Can you post the code of your asyn function as well as the call to `BeginRead()`, there are a lot of things we are guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

No, basically. It does not expose any peek API. You would have to maintain your own buffer. Note: you also can't write back into the read stream - if you write to a NetworkStream you are sending that data to the other machine.